# How to clean dataframe column filled with names using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( columns = ['Name']) 
df['Name'] = ['Aadam','adam','AdAm','adammm','Adam.','Bethh','beth.','beht','Beeth','Beth']
```

I want to clean the column in order to achieve the following:

```
df['Name Corrected'] = ['adam','adam','adam','adam','adam','beth','beth','beth','beth','beth']
df
```

Cleaned names are based on the following reference table:

```
ref = pd.DataFrame( columns = ['Cleaned Names']) 
ref['Cleaned Names'] = ['adam','beth']
```

I am aware of fuzzy matching but I'm not sure if that's the most efficient way of solving the problem.

Comment: How would you define "cleaned"? Without any definition, `adammm` is just as "clean" as `Adam`. Is a dictionary of English names your reference? Or do you have some other logic? Fuzzy matching might be helpful in both cases, but first you need to define what a "cleaned" name looks like.

Comment: I've added in a reference table to the question.

Comment: Hi! Did your query solved? if so then try considering [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so that the answer can be improved (or removed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
lst=['adam','beth']
out=pd.concat([df['Name'].str.contains(x,case=False).map({True:x})  for x in lst],axis=1)
df['Name corrected']=out.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:,0]
#Finally:
df['Name corrected']=df['Name corrected'].ffill()
#but In certain condition ffill() gives you wrong values
```

**Explaination:**

```
lst=['adam','beth']
#created a list of words
out=pd.concat([df['Name'].str.contains(x,case=False).map({True:x})  for x in lst],axis=1)
#checking If the 'Name' column contain the word one at a time that are inside the list and that will give a boolean series of True and False and then we are mapping The value of that particular element that is inside list so True becomes that value and False become NaN and then we are concatinating both list of Series on axis=1 so that It becomes a Dataframe
df['Name corrected']=out.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:,0]
#Backword filling values on axis=1 and getting the 1st column
#Finally:
df['Name corrected']=df['Name corrected'].ffill()
#Forward filling the missing values
```

Comment: Yes it works but I want to understand what each line of the code is doing

Comment: @Huey updated answer...kindly have a look ***:)***